# Top navigation bar hover underline effect

Tags: html, css, button, hover, uinavigationbar

For a project, I need to create the following navigation bar:

[image: navigation bar]

Like you can see the buttons of this navigation bar have mainly two specificities:

1. When we don't `hover` or `active` the navigation buttons, there is a 'grey underline' that takes the screen full width.
2. When we `hover` or `active` a button, the corresponding button's color and underline become blue.

To be honest, I'm completely lost about how to implement these two specificities.

At first, I tried to style the by default `underline` of the `.nav-button` (`text-decoration-offset`) and also their `border-bottom`, but I always have the two following problems:

1. My `underline` / `border-bottom` don't take the full width of the screen.
2. I can't limit where the `hover` / `active` effect on the line begins and end.

Then I tried to style the `border-bottom` of `#nav-menu`, but I again faced two problems:

1. Like the first time, I couldn't limit where the `hover` / `active` effect on the line begins and end.
2. `#nav-menu` is the container of my buttons, it means that when I `hover` or `active` on one of them, I can't affect their parent, in our case `#nav-menu` ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered)). And since **I'm allowed to use only HTML and CSS**, this second method can't be used.

Here is my code:

```css
#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.nav-button {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-button:hover {
  color: #0065FC;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-menu">
  <a class="nav-button">Accommodations</a>
  <a class="nav-button">Activities</a>
</nav>
```

I really thank in advance anybody who will be kind enough to try to help me :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `flex: 1` to get full width for `.nav-button`

```css
#nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.nav-button {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f2f2f2;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center
}

.nav-button:hover {
  color: #0065FC;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3465fc;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-menu">
  <a class="nav-button">Accommodations</a>
  <a class="nav-button">Activities</a>
</nav>
```